# Configuration of Owasp Zap on Azure Container Instances

Tags: owasp, azure-container-instances

I am trying to create an owasp zap instance using azure container instances using the following code:

```
$containerGroupName = "EW-owaspzap"
$containerDnsName = "EW-owaspzap"
$imageName = "owasp/zap2docker-stable"
$myIpAddress = (Invoke-WebRequest ifconfig.me/ip).Content.Trim()
$environmentVars = @{"api.key"="myreallysecureapikey";"api.addrs.addr.name"=$myIpAddress}
$containerGroup = Get-AzureRmContainerGroup -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Name $containerGroupName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
if (!$containerGroup) {
    New-AzureRmContainerGroup -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Name $containerGroupName -Image $imageName -Command zap-webswing.sh -Port 8080,8090 `
         -IpAddressType Public -DnsNameLabel $containerDnsName -RestartPolicy OnFailure -Location WestEurope -AzureFileVolumeShareName $storageShareName `
        -AzureFileVolumeMountPath '/output' -AzureFileVolumeAccountCredential $storageCredentials -EnvironmentVariable $environmentVars
     }
```

However I get the error:

The environment variable name in container 'EW-owaspzap' of container group 'EW-owaspzap' is invalid. A valid environment variable 
name must start with alphabetic character or '*', followed by a string of alphanumeric characters or '*' (e.g. 'my_name',  or 'MY_NAME',  or 'MyName')

according to this https://github.com/zaproxy/zaproxy/wiki/Docker I have the format of the environment variables correct. Is there anything else I have missed?

Answer (score 1):

This is ACI limitation - see [here](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/container-instances/container-instances-troubleshooting.md#naming-conventions) for naming limitation for env vars:

> | Environment variable | 1-63 |Case insensitive |Alphanumeric, and
>   underscore (_) anywhere except the first or last character

This is not an issue with Zap, but with ACI. 
This can be solved with a script that gets the env vars in Azure format and converts them to Zap's format (e.g. `api_key` to `api.key`). This is a pseudo-code (I did not test it), just to give you an idea:

```
export set api.key=$API_KEY
./zap
```

Create a new docker image based on Zap's official image, copy the script and use it to start Zap instead of the regular Zap's command.

Comment: Is this a script run after the container has started? Could you give an example?

Comment: Do you know if I could I just use the Azure Cli to overcome this limitation?

Comment: or just use an Arm template to generate the instance?

Comment: I don't know... Look on the documentation I've linked to, maybe it will be there

Comment: Omer is correct, you can work around this env var config constraint by using a startup script or an entrypoint command to set it manually. Another option would be using EXEC to start a live session and setting it yourself if you are looking for one-off interactive tests.

Answer (score 0):

For your issue, I think there is something you have misunderstood. The command in the link you posted `docker run -u zap -p 8080:8080 -i owasp/zap2docker-stable zap-x.sh -daemon -host 0.0.0.0 -port 8080 -config api.addrs.addr.name=.* -config api.addrs.addr.regex=true`, you should take a look at [`docker run`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/), there is no parameter like `-config`.

So, I think the command from `zap-x.sh` to the end is a whole bash command with the script `zap-x.sh`. You can check the parameter definition in the script `zap-x.sh`.

And the environment in PowerShell command is a Hashtable, you can get more details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.hashtable?view=netframework-4.7.2). Also, there are some limitations about [Naming conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-troubleshooting#naming-conventions) in Azure Container Instances.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to say. Are you saying my PS example above is missing -config? given the limitations of hashtables I am now looking at arm templates or azure cli as a means of injecting the startup parameters with dots in them. The script is just to start owasp zap with a UI, I don't really want to change this. If there are naming limitations for environment variables in azure, does that mean I can't do what I want to using ACI?

Comment: @johnstaveley I mean that the environment you set use a wrong type. You can set the environment as `$environmentVars = @{"api_key"="myreallysecureapikey";"api_addrs_addr_name"=$myIpAddress}` to meet the Hashtable limitation.

Comment: Changing the parameters in this way means the container does not pick them up correctly

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you got his working, but I used your powershell script & was able to create Zap container by replacing "." with "_" in $environmentVars array.

Comment: Good point, I didn't check it last night. Looks like with the underscore the scripts goes through without errors, but the values are not being set. Did you get it working any other way?